# Object share between more WPF windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm fairly new to WPF and I need your help with one object passing between more WPF windows.

Firstly I have my MainWindow with Button_Click event like this:

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Attribute ChooseYourAttr = new Attribute();
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
            ChooseYourAttr.Show();
            Character Player = new Character(firstTextbox.Text);
        }
```

And Then I have my second window called Attribute with something like this:

```
 private void attributeTopLabel_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String welcomeAttribute = "Ahh. I see! So ";
            attributeTopLabel.Content = welcomeAttribute;
        }
```

And I would like to have something like this: (Player.getName());

```
 private void attributeTopLabel_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String welcomeAttribute = "Ahh. I see! So " + Player.getName();
            attributeTopLabel.Content = welcomeAttribute;
        }
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the value through in the constructor:

```
private Character player = new Character();

public Attribute(Character player)
{
    this.player = player;
}

...

Character player = new Character(firstTextbox.Text);
Attribute ChooseYourAttr = new Attribute(player);

...

private void attributeTopLabel_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String welcomeAttribute = "Ahh. I see! So " + player.GetName();
    attributeTopLabel.Content = welcomeAttribute;
}
```

Comment: Attribute is the name of second window where I want to use my object Player created in first Window

Comment: Yes I know that, why are you telling me that? What part of my answer do you not understand?

Comment: Now I do understand, thanks for your answer! May I know if I can pass full object as a parameter in constructor? Probably yes why i could not tho..

Comment: Yes, of course, you can pass any object through the constructor. I updated my answer to reflect this.